# Cache issue in Google Apps Script spreadsheet read

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Specs-

- I have a source spreadsheet updated by multiple import functions from different sources. For some reasons, this source sheet has view only mode enabled (but I have enough permissions to read the data from the script). Note - it is a small sheet with only 150 lines, but data change frequency is 5 seconds.
- I used the below code to access the data and I could read the data as required

  ```
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid').getSheets[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  ```
- I try to read the data every 20 seconds to identify the change with below code

  ```
  // poll again in x miliseconds
  var t = 20000; // 20 second
  window.setTimeout(getData, t);
  ```
- But the problem here is, the data read is cached for 5-6 hours and every time thereon the scripts reads from cache only. The change in the source (every 5 seconds), never reflects here in the app.

I tried with [`Cache.put()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#put(String,String,Integer)), but no luck.

Any idea how to approach this issue?

Comment: The source sheet is in view mode only because it is updated so frequently. I'm guessing there are a number of cells which reference the imported regions as well. Reduce the frequency at which it updates and a lot of your issues will go away.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the source sheet modification. Also, as i said after a gap of 6 hours, even when source sheet is constantly getting updated, the app reads the data at that time. So I assumed this issue is because of some cache.I tried to change the read frequency to 10 minutes, but still no solution.

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question to be much more clear about what is going on, and where there is a problem. Including more of the code you are using may help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.